# Vue 3 google map circle is not being removed from the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, vuejs3

## Vue 3 google map circle is not being removed from the map

I am currently migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3.

In Vue 2 I could remove circles,
but in Vue 3 I run into the problem that the circles first disappear when removed.
But when zoom-in and zoom-out they reappear.
I do use the .setMap(null) method for removing the circles.

I use the circles to show a geofence for a POI (point of interest) and
This geofence also has a marker in the centre and I can remove the marker without any problems.

Has anyone else encountered the same problem?
Is this a problem people also run into in other frameworks?

##### How I create the map circles and markers

```js
 public LoadPoiMarkersAgain (
    googleMapLoader: IGoogleMapLoader
  ): HTMLMapMarker[] {
    const markers: HTMLMapMarker[] = []
    for (let i = 0; i < googleMapLoader.mapPoiData.length; i++) {
      const marker = createHTMLMapMarker({
        latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(
          {
            lat: googleMapLoader.mapPoiData[i].latitude,
            lng: googleMapLoader.mapPoiData[i].longitude
          },
          null,
          true
        ),
        map: googleMapLoader.map,
        data: googleMapLoader.mapPoiData[i],
        html: this.CreatePoiMarkerHTML(
          googleMapLoader,
          googleMapLoader.mapPoiData[i]
        )
      })
      const markerCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: googleMapLoader.map,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(
          {
            lat: googleMapLoader.mapPoiData[i].latitude,
            lng: googleMapLoader.mapPoiData[i].longitude
          },
          null,
          true
        ),
        radius: googleMapLoader.mapPoiData[i].radius
      })
      this.AddClickListenerToPoiMarker(marker, map)
      markers.push(marker)
      markerCircle.set('poiId', googleMapLoader.mapPoiData[i].poiId)
      googleMapLoader.mapCircles.push(markerCircle)
    }
    return markers
  }
```

##### How I remove the circles

```js
public RemoveMapMarkersData (
    googleMapLoader: IGoogleMapLoader
  ): void {
    if (googleMapLoader.mapCircles.length > 0) {
      googleMapLoader.mapCircles.forEach(
        (element: google.maps.Circle) => {
          element.setMap(null)
        }
      )
    googleMapLoader.mapCircles = []
    }
    // Some more code to remove markers
  }
```

#### What i have tried

##### attempt 1

I tried using

```js
element.setVisible(false)
```

This does not work either.

##### attempt 2

I tried changing the order for when the circle is removed versus the marker.
This does not work either.

##### attempt 3

I also tried removing the circle
Immediately after, I added them to the map.
That does seem to work.

```js
 public LoadPoiMarkersAgain (
    googleMapLoader: IGoogleMapLoader
  ): HTMLMapMarker[] {
    // previous code
    googleMapLoader.mapCircles.forEach((circle: google.maps.Circle) => {
circle.setMap(null)
    })
    // previous code
}
```

Could it be that Vue 3,
Is not passing the references correctly to my method?

#### Package

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader)

#### Google documentation

[Google docs remove circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes?hl=en#circle_remove)

[Google docs remove marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)

#### Extra

I have a gif that demonstrates the problem.

When I drag the map it should remove the circle.
But when zooming in and out, the circle reappears.

https://i.gyazo.com/b7310cc4d748da36e026104aff6cb2fe.gif

I have also created two sandboxes to demonstrate the problem:
(When you move your mouse out of the map, the circles will be removed)

**Vue 2**

[Vue 2 + google maps](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-google-maps-base-cricles-yiu9z0?file=/src/components/GoogleMapLoader.vue)

**Vue 3**

[Vue 3 + google maps](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-google-map-base-circles-ww1bfn?file=/src/components/GoogleMapLoader.vue)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I encountered the same issue whilst migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3, where markers were successfully being removed upon `setVisible(false)` but were then reappearing upon zoom.

Seeing console errors relating to `Proxy` led me to believe that the cause of the issue was due to the differences in the reactivity systems of Vue 2 and Vue 3 ([helpful article on Vue 3 reactivity](https://www.sitepoint.com/vue-3-reactivity-system/)).

For me the fix was to use [`markRaw()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#markraw) when creating the map, which essentially returns the Map Object itself without converting to a proxy.

```
<script>
    import { markRaw } from 'vue'

    export default {
        methods: {
            initMap () {
                map = markRaw(new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {...}))
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, 
but sadly enough it does not seem to be the solution for my google maps problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly enough I could not fix the problem in proper way,
but I have a place holder solution for now.

My place holder solution is to remove the map when removing the circles and markers. After removing the map I render / reinitialise the map again.

[Vue 3 - remove map when removing circles](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-google-map-base-circles-markers-custom-markers-remove-map-when-removing-circles-and-markers-ign6jb?file=/src/components/GoogleMapLoader.vue)

If I can remove the circles and markers as intended by google,
Then I will post an update on this again.